# Graphic issue after firmware update (Dell Precision 5540)

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics, dell, intel-graphics

I updated my Dell Precision 5540 firmware today with `sudo fwupdmgr update`.

The update was to 0.1.6.0 and it fetched from fwupd.org

The laptop uses a hybrid graphics setup and has an Nvidia quadro T2000 that is not enabled.

I noticed that now in certain 3rd party applications such as signal, typora, slack etc. I now have incredibly bad screen tearing and also strange horizontal lines on the dropdowns.

[screen torn example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcfGo.png)

I do not think issue is not related to my Nvidia graphics driver but rather the integrated Intel graphics.

Below is some info  I think could help:

---

`lspci -nn | egrep -i "3d|display|vga"`

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3e9b] (rev 02) 
>   01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1fb8] (rev a1)

---

`inxi -G`

> Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 3e9b
>              Card-2: NVIDIA Device 1fb8
>              Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) driver: intel
>              Resolution: 3840x2160@60.00hz
>              OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2)
>              version: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.8

---

contents of my grub file

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: Check your UEFI settings. Often update resets many settings to defaults. You may have a setting on which video is used that needs to be changed, also. To see if nVidia installed into your kernel. `dkms status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several fixes to this...

- upgrading mesa
- adding `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`
- trying to disable built-in graphics in UEFI (not possible on my model)
- purged intel and nividia drivers and started over
- installing nVidia drivers manually both open source and proprietary
- tried bumblebee
- reverted firmware
- forcing nvidia card on

In the end I did a dist upgrade to 19.10 which fixed the issue. Not ideal leaving LTS but whatever graphic drivers were included fixed my issue.